# JS - Check if string contain only 0

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a data of day and I need to check if it contain only 0.
How I can check if string contain only 0?
I want to do it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/^0*$/.test(subject)
```

returns `True` for a string that contains nothing but (any number of, including 0) zeroes. If you don't want the empty string to match, use `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've used match()

```
var subject = /^0+$/;
var starting_date = '00000000'
if (starting_date.match(subject)) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was filtering empty strings of binary and this seemed the most intuitive solution

```
!+"000" // true

!+"0010" // false
```