# What does !+ (not plus string) mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**What does `!+` (exclamation mark addition) mean in JavaScript?**

Why is `!+"000"` true?
Why is `!+"0010"` false?

Tries:

```
!+"000" // true
!+"00010" // false
!+"0a0" // true
!+"0,0" // true
!+[0,0,0] // true
!+[0,1,0] // true
true+"000" // true000
```

I've tried to search:

- [In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7615214/11582270)
- [What does "!--" do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34323527/11582270)
- [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/11582270)

Here I saw the code: [JS - Check if string contain only 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322503/11582270)

This information is hard to find on the Internet.

Comment: It's two separate unary operators

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). Operators can be combined. You wouldn’t ask about every possible combination, right?

Comment: `true + "000"` doesn’t use the unary `+`, but the binary one. The [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator) explains in detail what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is unary plus. It'll convert the expression that follows to a number.

Then, `!` negates the expression that follows: if it's truthy, the result is false. If it's falsey, the result is true.

A couple of examples:

```
!+"000"
!0 // because '000', when converted to a number, is 0
true

!+"00010"
!10 // because "00010", when converted to a number, is 10
false // because 10 is truthy

!+[0,1,0]
!NaN // because arrays can't be converted to numbers directly (usually)
true
```